# Is every specific representation induced by another representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathcal{S^n}$ be the set of real symmetric $n \times n$ matrices. Suppose $\sigma: G \to Aut(\mathcal{S}^n)$ is a representation. My preliminary question is:

Does, for every $\sigma$, there exist an orthogonal representation $\rho: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$\sigma_g(X)=\rho_g^TX\rho_g\ \ \ \forall g \in G,$$
for every $X \in \mathcal{S}^n$?

---

My thoughts:

According to the Skolem-Noether theorem, every automorphism of central simple algebras is an inner automorphism. Let $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the algebra of $n \times n$ matrices. For $\tilde\sigma_g \in Aut(M_n(\mathbb{R}))$, there exists $\tilde\rho_g \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\tilde\sigma_g(X)=\tilde\rho_g^{-1}X\tilde\rho_g$.

If $\tilde\sigma: G \to Aut(M_n(\mathbb{R}))$, then, for each $g$, there exists $\tilde\rho_g \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\tilde\sigma_g(\cdot)=\tilde\rho_g^{-1}(\cdot)\tilde\rho_g$. But can we say there exists a representation $\tilde\rho: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ whose image consists of these $\tilde\rho_g$?

If the answer is yes, how can we generalize all these to the case when $\sigma: G \to Aut(\mathcal{S}^n)$ since, in contrast to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, here $\mathcal{S}^n$ is not an algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=S_{N+1}$ for $N=n(n+1)/2$. Then $S_{N+1}$ has a $N$-dimensional standard representation:
$$V:=\big\{\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}a_ie_i:\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}a_{i}=0\big\}$$
where $\sigma\in S_{N+1}$ acts as $e_i\mapsto e_{\sigma(i)}$. There is an isomorphism of $V$ with $S^n$, since they are real vector spaces of the same dimension $n(n+1)/2$. However, there is no representation $\rho\colon S_{N+1}\to\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ with the properties you want, since $S_{N+1}$ has no non-trivial representations of dimension $<N$.

Comment: Doesn't $S_{N+1}$ have sign representation? $V$ is an irreducible representation, so Is it true that, if V was induced by $\rho$, then $\rho$ would have been an irreducible representation?  If the answer is yes, then we cannot find $\rho$ inducing $V$. However, if the answer is no, why is it not true that a direct sum of trivial and sign representation can construct $\rho$ such that it induces $V$?

Comment: Right sorry I should've said rho has to be a sum of trivial representations and sign representations. But then the alternating group would be in the kernel, a contradiction.